# How to use boost multiprecision's gmp_int type?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to use the boost multiprecision library in C++ and I've encountered problems with the gmp_int type.

My whole purpose in getting the boost library was to do arithmetic with arbitrarily large integers, so I made the following code just to see if everything worked:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace mp=boost::multiprecision;

int main()
{
    mp::gmp_int n;
    cin>>n;         //Here's the
    n=n*2           //problem (at least according to Xcode 5).
    cout<<n<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But it's throwing "*invalid operand*" errors in the lines I've marked above.

What went wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gmp_int` is the backend type.

Use `number<gmp_int>` to adapt it as a general arithmetic type. In this case, `mpz_int` is already that type:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cc0b3a3ac1fb12f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

int main() {
    mp::mpz_int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    n = n*2;
    std::cout << n << "\n";
}
```